# Look up 3 dataset & create new column for the result in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, left-join, vlookup

```
data_1 = {'ID': ['234', '456', '331', '134','372','456','765'], 
    'Result': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A']}
```

**I have first dataset
and then second dataset**

```
data_2 = {'ID': ['456', '132', '098', '134','372','456','234'], 
    'Result': ['B','B','B','B','B','B','B']}
```

**and then third dataset**

```
data_3 = {'ID': ['111', '132', '765', '134','234','999','765'], 
    'Result': ['C','C','C','C','C','C','C']}
```

**and the result I want is**

```
new_df = {'ID': ['234', '111', '456', '331','132','999','765'], 
    'Result': ['ABC','C','AB','A','BC','C','AC']}
```

I try to using left join and 3 dataset but still cannot create a new column or new data-frame. In excel I can try lookup from first dataset to second dataset, after I get, I lookup again to dataset 3 and lookup again from first dataset to third dataset. Is there any idea if I looking in pandas data-frame?

Comment: Please, add your code.

Comment: With a left join you wouldn't have 111 in the output, can you clarify?

Comment: why is `331` in your result but `134` is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
dfs = [data_1, data_2, data_3]
out = (pd.concat([d.set_index('ID') for d in dfs])
         .groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: ''.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))
         .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
    ID Result
0  098      B
1  111      C
2  132     BC
3  134    ABC
4  234    ABC
5  331      A
6  372     AB
7  456     AB
8  765     AC
9  999      C
```

If you really want a **left** join, then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
dfs = [data_1, data_2, data_3]
out = (pd.concat([d.set_index('ID') for d in dfs])
         .groupby('ID').agg(lambda x: ''.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))
         .reindex(data_1['ID']).reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
    ID Result
0  234    ABC
1  456     AB
2  331      A
3  134    ABC
4  372     AB
5  456     AB
6  765     AC
```

Comment: is `dict.fromkeys(x)` really necessary?

Comment: @TCMolenaar it depends on the exact logic. This is to keep unique values in order, which seems to the the case in the output. Otherwise a `set` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID', how='outer')
       .merge(df3, on = 'ID', how='outer')
       .drop_duplicates().fillna(''))
out.assign(result = out.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=1)).iloc[:, [0,-1]]
```

---

In case we have many dataframes (or want to compact code), we can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

out = reduce(lambda x, y: x.merge(y, on='ID', how='outer'), [df2, df3], df1)
out = out.drop_duplicates().fillna('')
out.assign(result = out.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=1)).iloc[:, [0,-1]]
```

---

Output:

```
     ID result
0   234    ABC
1   456     AB
5   331      A
6   134    ABC
7   372     AB
8   765     AC
10  132     BC
11  098      B
12  111      C
13  999      C
```